# BottlyPy - How to read UWSGI_SCHEME?

Tags: python, https, nginx, bottle

I have a python application running using BottlePy.

This application is routed by Nginx:

```
listen 443;
ssl on;
...

location / {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_param UWSGI_SCHEME https;
    uwsgi_pass unix:///var/run/uwsgi/uwsgi.sock;
}
```

Because I'm using the BottlePy micro-framework, I can't call `request.is_secure()` (No such method).

But is there a way to read the `UWSGI_SCHEME` value from code?

My goal is to be sure, from code, that the request used HTTPS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request.environ` was indeed the way to go.

http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.BaseRequest.environ

Thanks to **Mike** for pointing me the right direction.

```
print request.environ['wsgi.url_scheme']
```

Will print the scheme of the URL: http/https...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where the `is_secure` request method comes from but you could write your own using the WSGI environment ([request.environ](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.BaseRequest.environ))

```
def is_secure(request):
    if request.environ['SERVER_PORT'] == '443':
        return True
    return False
```